# Smart contract limitations in Ethereum & Fabric

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to make a smart contract to achieve the following automatically. But I stuck in the implementation. How can I run the (2) Tx without having B to sign the Tx, ie: I want it to run automatically once (1) is activated and condition (2) is ready.

Pseudocode(one):

```
A send 50 to B        (1)
if (B > 50)           (2)
    B send 10 to C    (3)
```

The code above involves multiple owners, ie. A, B and C. Firstly, A actives the contract by running/signing Tx (1). Then the contract checks condition (2). Now but how can run(3) automatically without having to force B to sign?

Ultimately, is the contract able to sign (or proxy sign) on behave of B?

---

**edit**

What about below in any chaincode? Can it run automatically, ie without D has to sign using D's private key in (3)?

Pseudocode(two):

```
A send 50 to B        (1)
if (something is true, say Z > 50)           (2)
    D send 10 to F    (3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ultimately, is the contract able to sign (or proxy sign) on behave of B?

**No.**

A starts the transactions by sending necessary funds to the contract, and then the contract disperses funds according to the rules. So, A -> contract, contract -> B and possibly, contract -> C.

Although it's outside the question raised, it will possibly help you avoid refactoring later to observe the best practice of separating the two sends if B and/or C are untrusted contracts. You would just do the accounting in the deposit step, and then use a withdrawal pattern as B & C claim their entitlements (separate transactions).

Hope it helps.

**Updated:**

Here's a rough outline that might give you some ideas. I wasn't sure if the > 50 was all-time total or a single payment > 50. It's a contrived example that expects you to pass in two valid addresses for B & C so the contract knows their addresses.

You can send amounts from any address (A) and the contract will keep track of `owedToB` and `owedToC`.

You should be able to send a transaction to `withdraw()` from B or C to claim the balance owed.

It's a little time-consuming to set everything up for a full test so just presenting "as is".

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Royalty {

  address public B;
  address public C;
  uint public owedToB;
  uint public owedToC;

  event LogPaymentReceived(address sender, uint amount);
  event LogPaid(address recipient, uint amount);

  // pass in two addresses, B & C for this simple constructor

  function Royalty(address addressB, address addressC) {
    B = addressB;
    C = addressC;
  }

  function pay()
    public
    payable
    returns(bool success)
  {
    owedToB += msg.value;

    // You can do B.balance > 50 but beware how it drops below 50 after withdrawal
    // A little more involved, but you can have totalReceipts AND totalPayments so owedToB is totalReceipts - totalPayments
    // It all depends on the business terms you're trying to enforce.

    if(msg.value > 50) {
      owedToC += 10;
      owedToB -= 10;
    }

    LogPaymentReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    return true;
  }

  function withdraw() 
    public
    returns(uint amountSent)
  {
    if(msg.sender != B && msg.sender != C) throw; // only B & C can withdraw

    uint amount;
    if(msg.sender == B) {
        amount = owedToB;
        owedToB = 0;
        if(!B.send(amount)) throw;
        LogPaid(B,amount);
        return amount;
    }
    if(msg.sender == C) {
        amount = owedToC;
        owedToC = 0;
        if(!C.send(amount)) throw;
        LogPaid(C,amount);
        return amount;
    }
    // we shouldn't make it this far
    throw;
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. If I understand you correctly, I have to do the calculation in the deposit step. But the problem now is that I only want to do 
    
     B send C amount 10 when the condition if (B > 50) is true, which in turn is based on the result of A send 50 to B

Comment: thanks a lot for the great example. the condition if (B > 50) means to check the current total balance of B. This is checked after B receives the 50 payment from A. So 1stly is the contract able to check B's balance? and 2ndly, if B.balance > 50, we then want to B.send (10) to C. In your example, you used/assigned all the deposit to owedToB. Then you checked the condition. If condition is true, you assigned 10 to  owedToC. Where does this 10 come from, A, B or C? In my original question, I want B to send 10 (part of B) to C.

Comment: You're right. There should be a owedToB -= 10. Fixed it.  It's possible to see balance but in practice that might not be the best way. For example, uint BBalance = B.balance; The problem with this is that it might float up and down with deposits and withdrawals, so most contracts are based on money flows, i.e. you wouldn't trigger things based on checking account balance; rather, some sort of accumulated receipts. In any case, the idea of the example is just to show the withdrawal pattern. The arithmetic is adaptable to the situation.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. Even with owedToB -= 10 only fixed this example. What if my (3) is B.send(20) to C. With the above fix, it becomes owedToB -= 20. Now we are risking 'overdraft' B's account.

Comment: It's obviously a contrived example to address the first question (one) and illustrate how to use arithmetic and withdrawals to move assets around.